# Lambda1 > SNS > SQS > Lambda2: Receiving oddly formatted events

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have the following architecture on AWS:

- A Lambda function (let's call it Lambda1), which publishes message onto...
- An SNS topic, which is subscribed to by...
- An SQS queue, which is subscribed to by...
- Another Lambda function (let's call it Lambda2).

The event being received by Lambda2 looks like this:

```
{
    "message": "{'Records': [{'messageId': 'REDACTED', 'receiptHandle': 'REDACTED', 'body': '{\\n  \"Type\" : \"Notification\",\\n  \"MessageId\" : \"REDACTED\",\\n  \"SequenceNumber\" : \"10000000000000054000\",\\n  \"TopicArn\" : \"arn:aws:sns:REDACTED\",\\n  \"Subject\" : \"Blackout\",\\n  \"Message\" : \"{\\\\\"channel\\\\\": \\\\\"REDACTED\\\\\", \\\\\"blackout\\\\\": {\\\\\"id\\\\\": 2452, \\\\\"name\\\\\": \\\\\"Name Goes Here\\\\\", \\\\\"location_id\\\\\": 2, \\\\\"reason\\\\\": \\\\\"Approaching capacity (9/1)\\\\\", \\\\\"start_date\\\\\": \\\\\"2022-08-05 00:00:00\\\\\", \\\\\"end_date\\\\\": \\\\\"2022-08-06 00:00:00\\\\\", \\\\\"blackout_scope\\\\\": \\\\\"product\\\\\", \\\\\"status\\\\\": \\\\\"pending create\\\\\", \\\\\"inventory_id\\\\\": 2444894}}\",\\n  \"Timestamp\" : \"2022-08-03T19:40:15.540Z\",\\n  \"UnsubscribeURL\" : \"https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=REDACTED\"\\n}', 'attributes': {'ApproximateReceiveCount': '3', 'SentTimestamp': '1659555615567', 'SequenceNumber': '18871590311294705152', 'MessageGroupId': '2452_create', 'SenderId': 'REDACTED', 'MessageDeduplicationId': 'REDACTED', 'ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp': '1659555615567'}, 'messageAttributes': {}, 'md5OfBody': '1be1a5ee5146faf13cb7cb5bb7f678d0', 'eventSource': 'aws:sqs', 'eventSourceARN': 'arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:659966244640:BlackoutsWorkerSpotHeroQueueNew.fifo', 'awsRegion': 'us-west-2'}]}",
    "levelname": "INFO",
    "name": "REDACTED",
    "asctime": "2022-08-03 20:46:58,732",
    "trace_id": null
}
```

Note the `body` in the `message`. It's been JSON-stringified and then escaped (which is expected – right?). But the `body` contains its own nested `message` key – which has *also* been JSON-stringified and then escaped. So the whole thing is a riot of backslashes.

Is this normal and expected? Or does it suggest a problem with the configuration of the various AWS resources? This is my first time implementing something like this.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you enable [Amazon SNS raw message delivery - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-large-payload-raw-message-delivery.html)?

Comment: I'll ask the obvious question... why are you including SNS and SQS in the flow?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: Because I'm new to Lambda/AWS, and I was told that this was a sensible approach. I assume because: (1) SQS allows retries and dead-letter queues; and (2) this approach allows Lambda1 to offload time-intensive operations to be processed asynchronously, so that Lambda1 doesn't exceed its 15-minute run limit. (Although perhaps invoking one Lambda from another is also asynchronous?)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: I'm not sure about RawMessageDelivery; I'm away from my work computer. But that sounds promising!

Comment: You can certainly invoke a lambda function from another lambda function. Typically, Amazon SNS would be used in a flow where multiple destinations want to receive the message. If SQS is the only subscriber to the SNS queue, then SNS probably isn't beneficial here. AWS Lambda has some retry logic so you don't need to use Amazon SQS, but that's your decision. And agreed -- it's never good to make a Lambda function wait for another function to complete.